# add ng-click to a div that was added using ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a div that is created in javascript using angularjs. Here it is
Js:

```
$scope.myHTML=$sce.trustAsHtml('<div
 ng-app="mainModule" 
 ng-controller="mainCtrl" 
 ng-click="updateText()" 
 class="squareButton ng-scope"> </div>");
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-bind-html="myHTML" class="screenDiv"></div>
```

The problem is that when i click on the div it does not call my updateText() method

```
$scope.updateText = function()
{
alert("worked");
}
```

The div does show up. the update method is in the mainCtrl controller.
the ng-click doesnt work what did i do wrong or is this just not supported yet.

Heres the page if it helps http://stevenjohnston.ca/ all of the squares "should" popup the alert but it doesnt.

Answer (score 2):

When you write something in your Html which is not known to Html and you want the angular to know those syntax like 'ng-click' you must compile it through the $compiler service. Otherwise it will be treated as a plain string by the angularj as well as the Html.
Use the following code.

```
function htmlGeneratorController($scope, $compile, $sce){
$scope.myHTML=$compile($sce.trustAsHtml('<div ng-app="mainModule" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-click="updateText()" class="squareButton ng-scope"> </div>'))($scope);
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129918/how-to-bind-ng-click-function-that-was-inserted-as-html-trustashtml however getting `[$sce:unsafe]'? Any thoughts? :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason for binding HTML to every square?

It would be easier to just use some grid or table and bind ng-click to each cell.

So you can move controlle outside div

```
 <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <!-- Create Table or Grid .Inside each cell add-->
    <div ng-click="updateText()"></div>
</body>
```