# How to bind ng-click to a HTML block inserted inside of a directive embedded HTML block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-bind-html

**Plnkr:** http://plnkr.co/edit/6xe46opL2kpgQrf7VaEu?p=preview

I have a `ng-click="switchCurreny()` function that I'm trying to get working on an block of HTML that is placed inside of another block of HTML that is embedded on the page from my `directive`.

My `app-main` controller that places another block of HTML into the directive placed HTML, also contains the `ng-click` function I'm trying to get working:

```
var app = angular.module('app-main', ['ngAnimate', 'wallet-directives'])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {

    var vm = $scope;
    var currency = 'USD';
    vm.modal = false;
    vm.modal_send = false;
    vm.modalActive = false;

    // HTML to be placed inside of directive placed HTML in <wallet-modals>
    var send_html = '<div ng-click="switchCurreny()" class="btn_usd noselect">'+currency+'</div>';

    // Open the modal, then place send_html into modal_bind:
    vm.openModal = function($event) {
        vm.modal = true;                             // show modal
        vm.modal_send = true;                        // show modal_send 
        vm.modal_bind = $sce.trustAsHtml(send_html); // stick send_html inside of modal_bindd
    }

    vm.closeModal = function() {
        vm.modal = false;
        vm.modal_send = false;
    };

    // ng-click function inside of send_html:
    vm.switchCurreny = function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        if (currency === 'USD') {
            currency = 'BTC';
        } else {
            currency === 'USD';
        }
    };
}]);
```

My Directive with the Modal HTML

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('wallet-directives', [])
    .directive('walletModals', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div ng-show="modal_send" class="modal"><p>The Modal, button below:</p><br/><div ng-bind-html="modal_bind"></div></div>'
        };
    });

})();
```

HTML

```
<!-- Directive goes here -->
<wallet-modals></wallet-modals>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you basically have to recompile after you have inserted new html code, because angular just inserts the new code into your div as far as I understand it and doesn't compile it.

It seems to me like the proper way would be to create a directive that handles your recompile. A possible solution has been discussed here: http://jesusjzp.github.io/blog/2014/07/30/compile-ngbind-angularjs/

Here is an excerpt from the link above (if the link ever dies) that shows how it is supposed to look like:

```
HTML:

<div ng-bind-html="details" do-compile="scope"></div>

JS:

angular.module('yourAppName')
  .directive('doCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var selectedScope = attrs.doCompile && scope.$eval(attrs.doCompile);
      if (!element.hasClass('compiled')) {
        element.addClass('compiled');
        compile(element.contents())(selectedScope || scope);
      }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Ah I believe you are right! I haven't used a `directive` in awhile.. going to hack away and bbiab

Comment: I edited my answer, so it includes the most crucial part from the link.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that example from the jsfiddle they posted, same results :/ I added the 2nd `directive` with `$compile` and nothing happened. Any chance you could take a look at my Plnkr? I feel like it's 2 lines away hehe. Thanks though, I'm using a directive now and updated my original question.

Comment: Ok completed updated my question with new code, containing my directive. I was able to get all the HTML to load up, now back to my original question of why I can't get my `ng-click` to work on the embedded HTML

Comment: Ok checking this question, but please note... I was not able to accomplish what I was trying to do. I was working with 2 HTML blocks, could not get that to work so now having to use 2 directives. That way my functions will work with them, instead of trying to find the scope of an embed inside of an embed.